# How to open an embedded '.py' file from Microsoft Powerpoint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, powerpoint

[image]I have a PPT file, '.py' file is embedded with that ppt, I'm unable to see that '.py' file. How to open an embedded '.py' file from MS-powerpoint? Is it possible to view an embedded '.py' file from MS-powerpoint ?

Thank you

Comment: How do you know its in there? If you see the file content, just copy and save it. Or right click on it works.

Comment: @heLomaN I have added one screen-shot, when I click on that embedded file, one pop-up message is coming, if I click on that open button, one cmd box will pop-up & will close that cmd box automatically. I'm unable to see the contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any method to open embedded python file from MS-powerpoint. so, I followed an alternate way to open that embedded file. 
Copied that embedded file to an excel sheet , by right clicking on that copied file, you will get set of options, select "save to file option" ,set any path, save it.
 [image]